# How to resize the width of the UITextView according the?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I want to ask how to resize the `UITextView` to fit the text will display on the screen.

For example

[image]

**Resize** the `UITextView` to

[image]

Could anyone help me out or give me some advise.
Thanks

Tips:

I tried
`sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:` ,Not work

Comment: Can you show the code you are using now?

Comment: i think it not possible,we set dynamically height for UITextView not set width

Comment: @NANNAV Yah, you are right.So I'm considering if there is a way to calculate the size programmatically.I think if we know the spacing between text to the border of view, it could be got by using sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know the `CGSize` that is taken by your `NSString` if rendered on a single line, use `CGSize sz = [textView.text sizeWithFont:_textView.font]` then adjust your frame given this size value.

If you need to know the `size` taken by your text if rendered on multiple lines, wrapping it if the text reaches a given width, use `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` instead, etc.

Comment: sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode works.But there is a problem that how to get the size property.The size of textView is bigger than the text actually use.Then it will return a wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago (but with the **height** of the `UITextView`) and I created a `CGRect` with a size that would fit the `contentSize` of the `UITextView`, Try the code below

```
// assuming that you have a UITextView named textView with some text on it
CGRect textFrame = self.textView.frame;
textFrame.size.width = self.textView.contentSize.width;
self.textView.frame = textFrame;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one  it worked for me

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
 frame.size.width = _textView.contentSize.width;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

happy coding....